# Capturing of data fields in submission form from Adobe Analytics

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I would like to capture few data fields `company name` `user name` filled by customers and display it on Adobe Analytics.Is the below code perfect ? If yes where to apply in the`s_code.js` file and what settings has to be done in AA in order to display ?

## My Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var  compName = $("#compnamelabelidl").text();
     var uname = $("input[name=email]").val();
     console.log("User company name --> " + compName + ", uname is ==> " + uname);
});
```

Comment: well your first problem is unless those form fields are pre-filled out when the page is loading, trying to get the values of them on dom ready isn't going to return anything, since it's very unlikely the visitor managed to fill in those fields before dom ready!

Comment: Much of this would depend on when the form field data is available. If the form info is available after submit (next page, for example), you can use the subsequent page load to determine if the data exists and send it off as part of the analytics page view.